# C# async - Exception not handled

Tags: c#

This code here is not handling the Exception thrown, when it cant connect to the Server. Any Ideas why? Thanks!

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartClient();

        }
async private Task StartClient()
{
    try
    {
        await ConnectToServerAsync();
    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
    {
        MesssageBox.Show("TEST");
    }
}

private Task ConnectToServerAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.Connect(host, port));
}
```

Comment: `await` will wrap all exception in AggregateException - you should catch for that first and then check `aggregateException.InnerExceptions` collection for actual exception which caused error

Comment: Even if I catch all Exceptions it gets not handled

Comment: *Don't* use `async void`. It can't be awaited and any exceptions it raises can't be handled. It's only meant for event handlers

Comment: @Milney `await` exists so you *don't* need to call a dispatcher. If `StartClient` is called on the UI thread, then `Show` will be called on the UI thread

Comment: You should return `Task` from `StartClient` - all exceptions and completed results can be handled only from returned Task. `async void` return nothing which can be handled.'

Comment: Why are you calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` like this? Why not `Task.Run`? Even better, why don't you use the *asynchronous* version of Connect? [TcpClient.ConnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138320(v=vs.110).aspx) for example is a truly asynchronous method while `Task.Run(()=>client.Connect())` just fakes it

Comment: @Fabio `Task.Result` throws an `AggregateException`, `await` throws the exception that occured

Comment: As has been mentioned, `async void` will not catch exceptions, there is nothing to `await` and there is nothing holding the exception. Use `async Task` instead.

Comment: You need to post reproduceable example, because code you provided should catch that exception (assuming `client.Connect` indeed throws `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`).

Comment: One more thing to mention: even if the exception is traversed up to your outer async code, it can be wrapped (let say, into AggregatedException like TPL does) so you have to "catch()" with correct exception type.

Comment: Found out that if i execute the Compiled assembly, the catch block fires perfectly fine, only while debugging catch block is not triggered. Why is this?

Comment: You are *still* using `async void`. There's no point in investigating anything until this is fixed.

Comment: And *await* it too. If you *don't* await the task. you *won't* get any results or exceptions. Any exceptions throws that *aren't* caught will end up as an unhandled background exception.

Comment: Also move the call *outside* the constructor, eg to the Load event. The form doesn't exist *yet* in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: "async void" is very dangerous construct that should almost never appear in your production code. Async method is not a list of statements internally, it's kind of state machine that switches from one "await" statement to another, doing various things in-between while "awaiting". So, once you got an exception raised inside that state machine, you need special context to preserve the stack trace etc. Void methods do not provide such a context. Return Task or Task<something> instead.

As a further reading, I could recommend Phil Haack's very nice blogpost: http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems with this code. First, using `async void` is only meant for *event handlers*. An `async void` method can't be awaited and any exceptions it throws can't be handled. Second, `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>client.Connect(host,port))` fakes asynchronous execution. It still blocks a thread. Asynchronous execution means that *no* thread is blocked while waiting for the operation to complete.

I assume you use TcpClient. This class already has a [ConnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138320(v=vs.110).aspx) method that connects in an asynchronous manner. You could simplify your code to this:

```
private async Task StartClient()
{
    try
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(host,port);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you want to start the client in response to a UI event, eg a button click, you'd write :

```
async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await StartClient();
}
```

or

```
async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        await StartClient();
        //Work with the client
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Finally, use a logging library instead of `MessageBox.Show`, eg `log4net` so you don't lose exception messages due to threading issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, I do not use TcpClient, I use an external lib which handles Client - Server - Communication.

Even if I change the return type of StartClient to Task ,its not working (leaving everything else as it is in my initial Post)

Comment: @azmd108 First, exceptions do work. Did you try debugging? Did you set a breakpoint in the `catch` statement? Are you sure there *is* an exception to begin with? If execution doesn't enter the exception handler, it's because there is no exception to handle. On the other hand, if you call that `async void` method from a console application, the application may terminate before the method has a chance to run

Comment: Its not jumping inside the Catch-Statement - that is my Problem - its not catching. Yes, there is a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException thrown

Comment: @azmd108 post *actual* code that reproduces the problem then. Who calls `StartClient`? *Do* you await for it to complete? What happens if you replace `client.Connect` with a `throw new Exception()` ?

Comment: Found out that if i execute the Compiled assembly, the catch block fires perfectly fine, only while debugging catch block is not triggered. Why is this?

Comment: Because it doesn't happen. You still haven't posted the code that calls `StartClient`, or a reproducible example.  It may simply be that `Connect` *doesn't* throw. Replace *your* code with a `throw new Exception()`. You'll see the exception *is* caught, unless you use `async void` and the operation takes so long that the application terminates

Comment: What you mean "it doesnt happen". Of course it happens. Only when I debug, Exception is not handled, if I start compiled .exe, it gets handled.

Please see code in my initial answer, Form1 Constructor is calling the StartClient() method.

Maybe I have to change some Settings in Debugmode how Exceptions are handled?